# C API with structures in Swift - immutable value as inout argument

Tags: objective-c, c, swift, struct

I'm working on a Swift 3 project that involves using some C APIs that I bridged from Objective-C.

Here is a sample snippet of the structure of the API:

```
typedef struct
{
    StructMode     mode;
    StructLevel    level;
} TargetStruct;

typedef struct
{
    . . . 
    TargetStruct        *targetStruct;
    OtherStruct         *otherStruct;
    NonPointerStructA   nonPointerStructA;
    NonPointerStructB   nonPointerStructB;
    . . .
} InnerStruct;

typedef struct
{
    InnerStruct     innerStruct;
    OtherStructB    otherStructB;
} OuterStruct;
```

In my Swift code, my goal is to set a value of the TargetStruct from the OuterStruct, like the following:

```
// run function that returns an instance of TargetStruct
var targetStruct: TargetStruct = initializeTargetStruct()

// assign targetStruct to outerStruct
outerStruct.innerStruct.targetStruct = &targetStruct
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot pass immutable value of TargetStruct as inout argument
```

If I set a value of a struct without the *, it will work fine:

```
var nonPointerStructA: NonPointerStructA = initializeNonPointerStructA()
outerStruct.innerStruct.nonPointerStructA = nonPointerStructA
```

I have tried setting the value of targetStruct like this, but for now I have no way to test it:

```
var targetStruct: TargetStruct = initializeTargetStruct()
outerStruct.innerStruct.targetStruct.initialize(from: &targetStruct, count: 0)
```

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, prefix `&` is not an *address-of* operator. It is just needed to clarify that some expression is passed to an `inout` parameter. So, your first code is syntactically invalid in Swift.

Your C-structs are imported to Swift as follows:

```
struct TargetStruct {
    var mode: StructMode
    var level: StructLevel

    //some auto generated initializers...
}

struct InnerStruct {
    //...
    var targetStruct: UnsafeMutablePointer<TargetStruct>!
    var otherStruct: UnsafeMutablePointer<OtherStruct>!
    var nonPointerStructA: NonPointerStructA
    var nonPointerStructB: NonPointerStructB

    //some auto generated initializers...
}

struct OuterStruct {
    var innerStruct: InnerStruct
    var otherStructB: OtherStructB

    //some auto generated initializers...
}
```

(If something wrong, please tell me.)

As you see, `targetStruct` in your `InnerStruct` is a pointer, and `initialize(from:count:)` tries to write to the pointed region, but at the time you call `initialize(from:count:)`, `targetStruct` holds its initial value `nil`, you know what happens when dereferencing null-pointer.

---

One way is to allocate a memory for the `TargetStruct` and use the pointer to the allocated region.

```
func allocateAndInitializeTargetStruct() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<TargetStruct> {
    let targetStructRef = UnsafeMutablePointer<TargetStruct>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    targetStructRef.initialize(to: initializeTargetStruct())
    return targetStructRef
}

outerStruct.innerStruct.targetStruct = allocateAndInitializeTargetStruct()
```

This is a more general way than below, but you need to explicitly `deinitialize` and `deallocate` the allocated region. That's sort of hard to manage.

---

If you can confine the usage of the `outerStruct` in a single code-block, you can write something like this:

```
var targetStruct = initializeTargetStruct()
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &targetStruct) {targetStructPtr in
    outerStruct.innerStruct.targetStruct = targetStructPtr

    //Use `outerStruct` only inside this code-block
    //...
}
```

In this case, the pointer held in `outerStruct.innerStruct.targetStruct` (== `targetStructPtr`) is only valid inside the closure and you cannot use it outside of it.

---

If any of the codes above does not fit for your use case, you may need to provide more context to find the best solution.

---

An example of nested use of `withUnsafeMutablePointer(to:_:)`:

```
var targetStruct = initializeTargetStruct()
var otherStruct = initializeOtherStruct()
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &targetStruct) {targetStructPtr in
    withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &otherStruct) {otherStructPtr in
        outerStruct.innerStruct.targetStruct = targetStructPtr
        outerStruct.innerStruct.otherStruct = otherStructPtr

        //Use `outerStruct` only inside this code-block
        //...
    }
}
```

When you need more pointers to set, this nesting would be a mess, but it's the current limitation of Swift.

---

An example of `deinitialize` and `deallocate`:

```
extension InnerStruct {
    func freeMemberStructs() {
        if let targetStructRef = targetStruct {
            targetStructRef.deinitialize()
            targetStructRef.deallocate(capacity: 1)
            targetStruct = nil
        }
        if let otherStructRef = otherStruct {
            otherStructRef.deinitialize()
            otherStructRef.deallocate(capacity: 1)
            otherStruct = nil
        }
    }
}

outerStruct.innerStruct.targetStruct = allocateAndInitializeTargetStruct()
outerStruct.innerStruct.otherStruct = allocateAndInitializeOtherStruct()

// Use `outerStruct`
//...

outerStruct.innerStruct.freeMemberStructs()
```

The code may not seem to be too complex (just a bunch of boilerplate codes), but it's hard to find when or where to do it. As your `InnerStruct`  may be embedded in another struct which may need to be `deinitilize`d and `deallocate`d...

Hope you can find your best solution.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer! In my scenario, I have to initialize different structs. Would it be okay to have several of those blocks for each struct I want to initialize?

For example:

`var targetStruct = initializeTargetStruct()

var otherTargetStruct = initializeOtherTargetStruct()

withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &targetStruct) {targetStructPtr in
    outerStruct.innerStruct.targetStruct = targetStructPtr
}

withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &otherTargetStruct) {otherTargetStructPtr in
    outerStruct.innerStruct.otherTargetStruct = otherTargetStructPtr
}`

Comment: @mugiwara528, if you have my second code in mind, you need to **nest** `withUnsafeMutablePointer(to:_:)`. Do not use several `withUnsafeMutablePointer(to:_:)` sequentially.

Comment: I see. I think nesting `withUnsafeMutablePointer(to:_:)` is not the best way for me then. How would one go about using `deinitialize` and `deallocate` ? Thank you